# Microsoft mouse not scrolling

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, macos

I've got a Microsoft Bluetooth Mobile 3600 ([Link to microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/d/microsoft-bluetooth-mobile-mouse-3600/8v7ckdtwx9h2?activetab=pivot:%C3%BCbersichttab)) that I would like to use with my iMac.

I got this mouse for quiet some time and used in with my MacBookPro 2017 when it came out. With the MacBook everything was working fine and at some point I switched to a Magic Mouse 2.

Now I would like that exact same mouse (not bought new, the old one) with my iMac running macOS Monterey 12.4 and the scroll isn't working. Sometimes it picks it up and scrolls 2mm down but that's it.

Why this is weird:

- back then it was working with macOS (probably Sierra or High Sierra depending on the time, as I said 2017)
- When I connect the mouse to a Windows machine everything is working, so no physical damage on the mouse
- Everything else on the mouse is working in macOS, I can move it normally, left/ right click working great without any lag

As far as I understand there are no drivers for macOS in general, right?

So any ideas what could cause this? I do have the Magic Mouse and the Microsoft mouse connected at the same time though. BUT when I use another bluetooth mouse with scroll wheel while the Magic Mouse is connected everything is working.
So it seems related to that specific mouse. On a MacBook Air M1 the same problem occurs.

Any suggestions what to do (else than buying a new mouse)?